# Wordpress Shortcode not working with WP Codex command and PHP

Tags: php, html, wordpress, shortcode

Below is a php issue I am having, it works in other ways but doesn't work the way I wish too.

Basically I wish to add the WP login and logout commands to the the A-HREF links, but the closing short code doesn't seem to be taken effect and I would like to know why and hopefully fix this problem.

```
<?php
    echo do_shortcode('[not-level-visitors]') .
        '<div id="SignUp">
            <ul>
                <li><img src="http://dev.universitycompare.com/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/images/icons/user_icon.png" alt="User Icon My Account University Compare" />
                    <a href="http://dev.universitycompare.com/account/" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px -8px;">My Account</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="' .  wp_logout_url($redirect) . '">Log Out</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>' . 
    do_shortcode('[/not-level-visitors]');
?>
```

Basically the above code is kind of working, but I just need the closing shortcode to work as it appears in my html and is not being recognised - I have created the above code from this below snippet that I am already using that works completely:

```
<?php
    echo do_shortcode('[level-visitors]
        <div id="SignUp">
            <ul>
               <li>
                   <a href="#">Sign Up</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                   <a href="#">Login</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    [/level-visitors]');
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference I spotted is the single call vs multiple calls to do_shortcode, I assume it's failing to match the regex.

Maybe this will work:

```
    echo do_shortcode('[not-level-visitors]
        <div id="SignUp">
            <ul>
                <li><img src="http://dev.universitycompare.com/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/images/icons/user_icon.png" alt="User Icon My Account University Compare" />
                    <a href="http://dev.universitycompare.com/account/" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px -8px;">My Account</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="' .  wp_logout_url($redirect) . '">Log Out</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>[/not-level-visitors]');
```

Comment: Brilliant! Spot on and worked flawlessly, it has to be contained in the same brackets otherwise the shortcode breaks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to remove the extra opening/closing parentheses and extra do_shortcode call.

```
<?php
echo do_shortcode('[not-level-visitors]' .
    '<div id="SignUp">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="http://dev.universitycompare.com/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/images/icons/user_icon.png" alt="User Icon My Account University Compare" />
                <a href="http://dev.universitycompare.com/account/" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px -8px;">My Account</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="' .  wp_logout_url($redirect) . '">Log Out</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>' . 
'[/not-level-visitors]');
?>
```